# Upload JSON data as a file

Tags: javascript, json, file-upload, xmlhttprequest, google-cloud-storage

I have an object (data), and I need to convert it to JSON and upload it to a CDN. I plan to use `JSON.stringify()` and pass it the javascript object

It works perfectly upload files to the CDN from the browser, I wonder how I can emulate a FormData

The code I use to upload a file to the CDN is: (As an example)

```
const data = new FormData();
data.append('signature', auth.signature);
data.append('key', auth.id);
data.append('policy', auth.policy);
data.append('GoogleAccessId', auth.serviceAccount);
data.append('bucket', 'assets-visualive');
data.append('file', file);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After much research the solution was in [Using FormData Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/)

Convert the object to JSON with `JSON.stringify()`, then create a blob of data and upload it as a file

```
const object = { key: 'data', n: 10 };
const json = JSON.stringify(object);
const blob = new Blob([json], { type: 'text/json' });

const data = new FormData();
data.append('file', blob);
```

Answer (score -1):

How do you make your ajax call? Be sure to include "processData : false" option.

Comment: The problem is like converting a JSON to type "file", to be able to upload it via file upload